# closed by community and deleted

Tags: discussion

From what i know community is a bot, no human observes and decides.

In this inarticulate edit https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52530/difference-betwddddddddddddddddd  and content "pls help" I sincerely hope that no real call for help has been denied.

I was going to add a comment to the effect "go to a hospital emergency if you need help" but am unable to do so now. It may be that the user had ingested some of those substances he listed in the first version of the question and really needed help.

Comment: A post like that is quite unlikely to be a real call for help, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

That was a spam flag deletion: someone flagged it as spam, and I counterflagged. Spam flags lead to the post being deleted/locked by Community.

I don't think he ingested anything -- I've seen this often on other sites -- a user defaces his own post after it is closed :/

Comment: Yep. Looks like the system worked in response to a bad question and a really bad edit. Perhaps a polite comment could have headed the vandalism off at the pass, but at some point users need to bring a little judgement to what they post and they certainly don't get any points for throwing a tantrum when they don't get what they wanted.

Comment: @dmckee: When I counterflagged it, I didn't even know that it was vandalism (didn't see the edit). I just assumed it was one of those "ooh cool a text box let's type in it" people that seem to be pretty common on the Net nowadays :/